# How to set up a subdomain in nsd3

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, nsd

nsd3 is very little-known but super-lightweight and stable DNS server which makes it a great alternative to bind9 be used on low-end boxes. There is a very good tutorial [here](https://forum.ramhost.us/bbs/viewtopic.php?pid=1032) that describe how to set it up. My problem is that I need to set up a subdomain subd1.example.com that will be severed on another VPS. I tried to add

subdmn1.mymaindomain.com.   IN     1.2.3.5
(Assuming that my destination IP is 1.2.3.5)
Then I

```
nsdc rebuild
service nsd3 restart
```

However the subdmn1.mymaindomain.com fails to resolve to the IP. Any clues will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If that's exactly the record from your zonefile, you are missing the record type, and possibly the TTL.

The correct way would be:

```
subdmn1.mymaindomain.com. 86400 IN A 1.2.3.5
```

It might be possible to skip the TTL - I have never tried this in nsd.

If this still does not resolve your problem, have a look in the nsd logs. Note that you don't have to restart to reload the zones, you can use `nsdc reload` after the `nsdc rebuild`.

Also, assuming that this record is in the `mymaindomain.com.`, zone, you could shorten `subdmn1.mymaindomain.com.` to `subdmn1` (note the lack of a trailing dot there).